# Get CPU Core and CPU Count on Linux

Tags: linux, redhat

In this output to lscpu, is it correct to say that it has 2 cores and 1 cpu?

```
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's it. For instance here's the relevant part for an EPYC (1 processor, 4 chips on the CPU, 16 cores, 2 threads per core):

```
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    16
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          4
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I just noticed that I missed a line. The output I have is this: `CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1`. So wouldn't that be 4 cpus and 2 cores?

Comment: @user99201 No, because your dual-core CPU is hyperthreading.